# How do command line arguments work?

Tags: c, command-line-arguments

As the question mentions, how do command line arguments work in C(in general any language). The logical explanation I could think of is, the operating system sets some kind of environmental values for the process when it starts.
But if it's true I should not be able to access them as argp[i] etc(I modified the main to expect the 2nd argument as char **argp instead of **argv). Please explain.

Comment: Why do you think you shouldn't you be able to access them as argp[i] ? (Note that function argument names are usually not meaningful in a compiled program, naming the 2. argument to main `argv` is just a convention, you could name it `FOOBAR` if you want)

Comment: The arguments to `main` are just like the arguments to any other function. The names doesn't really matter, you can even have different argument names in function prototypes and the actual function, as long as the types matches. Where the arguments to `main` comes from doesn't really matter, just treat them as any integer and array-of-pointers (or pointer-to-pointer in your case).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'll try to explain the implementation a bit more than other answers.
I'm sure there are inaccuracies, but hope it describes the relevant parts well enough.

Under the shell, you type `./myprog a b c`.
The shell parses it, and figures out that you want to run `./myproj` with three parameters.
It calls `fork`, to create a new process, where `./myprog` would run.
The child process, which still runs the shell program, prepares an array of 5 character pointers. The first will point to the string `./prog`, the next three are to the strings `a`, `b` and `c`, and the last is set to NULL.
Next, it calls the `execve` function, to run `./myprog` with the parameter array created.
`execve` loads `./myprog` into memory, instead of the shell program. It releases all memory allocated by the shell program, but makes sure to keep the parameter array.
In the new program, `main` is called, with the parameter array passed to it as `argv`.

Comment: Why doesn't `execve` require an `argc` argument?

Comment: Actually, the array will contain five entries, don't forget the program name in the first (zeroth) place.

Comment: And it might use some other mechanism than fork-exec to actually create the new process. It's entirely up to the OS, and doesn't really matter anyway for the purposes of this question. Whatever mechanism is used by the OS and the shell to run a command, it must involve passing the command-line arguments. This is the UNIX-like way of doing things, where the arguments are "cloned" by `fork` and "survive" `execve`.

Comment: @SteveJessop, You're right, I explained one implementation, which probably isn't an accurate description of any OS. But I think describing a simple mechanism which could have been used often helps understand things better than just saying what you're guaranteed to get.

Comment: @ugoren: I agree, a concrete example is very useful. The defined behavior is just, "the right array shows up by the time `main` is entered", which doesn't illustrate anything ;-)

Answer (score 5):

In a C program the OS creates an array of pointers to zero terminated strings. The count is passed as `argc` and the array is passed as `argv`. You already know this. The names `argc` and `argv` don't matter. You can use any name. The data types and the order do matter... `argv` must be `int` and `argc` must be `char*[]` or `char**`. Other languages have similar mechanisms. For example C# passes a single `string[]` argument which is a .NET array and keeps track of it's length internally. More information is available here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_function#C_and_C.2B.2B

Environment variable names are separate from names of variables in your program. `argc` and `argv` are not environment variables... they are variables local to `main()`.

To access environment variables use `getenv()`.

**Update:** You wanted to know how these are made available to the program. It is the OS which does that. But before the OS can do so, the program invoking your executable -- the caller -- gets to process your command line. Usually the caller is a shell (`bash`, `csh`, `zsh`, `cmd.exe`) or a desktop environment like GNOME or Windows Explorer. The caller passes these arguments via [execve](http://linux.die.net/man/2/execve) (on *nix) or [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (on Windows).

Answer (score 2):

What ever the name you give to main arguments, what is important is their type and order. To get env vars use this closure:

```
int main(int argc, char ** myCommandLineArguments, char ** myEnvironmentVars)
```

Is this what you're wondering?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually, my question is not about how to access them, but about who and how makes them available to the program.